# window.click does not fire on Safari for iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari, touch

This code works fine in desktop browsers:

```
$(window).click(function() {...});
```

But in Safari on the iPad, it simply doesn't fire.  Is this not supported?  What is the correct way to be notified when someone touches somewhere in the browser window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery UI supports `touch` for devices. . You could bind click and touch listeners on the same set of events.

```
$(window).bind("click touchstart", function(){...});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  By the way, the event seems to be "touchstart" not "touch".  I've edited the answer to reflect the correct code.

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this

```
var clickOrTap = ( typeof document.body.ontouchend === "undefined" ) ? 'click' : 'touchend';
$( "body" ).on( clickOrTap, function() { ... } );
```

It checks if the device has a `touchend` event and if it doesn't it means you're on desktop, so the listener will wait for `click`. If it defined then you're on a touch device and you can listen for touch events.

Comment: Wish I could mark both as answers, since you helped as well (particularly "touchstart" vs "touch"), but I think the "bind" syntax is cleaner.